# Rendering the image of a control in Windows from a handle to it

Tags: c#, .net, controls, rendering, handle

I am using the following code to render the image of a particular control given a pointer to it; the control is hosted in one application and this console application picks up a pointer to it and renders that control to a bitmap (you can dump this code into a new console application and try it out, you will just need to replace the path and the pointer to some other control's handle you wish to use):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BitmapGenerator
{
    class Program
    {

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdc, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, IntPtr hdcSrc, int x1, int y1, uint rop);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ControlToPNG(1920, 1080, IntPtr.Zero, @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Output.png");
        }

        static void ControlToPNG(int controlWidth, int controlHeight, IntPtr controlHandle, string path)
        {
            using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))
                ControlToPNG(controlWidth, controlHeight, controlHandle, fileStream);
        }

        static void ControlToPNG(int controlWidth, int controlHeight, IntPtr controlHandle, Stream stream)
        {
            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(controlWidth, controlHeight))
            using (var destinationGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            using (var sourceGraphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(controlHandle))
            {
                IntPtr destinationHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                IntPtr sourceHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                try
                {
                    destinationHandle = destinationGraphics.GetHdc();
                    sourceHandle = sourceGraphics.GetHdc();
                    BitBlt(destinationHandle, 0, 0, controlWidth, controlHeight, sourceHandle, 0, 0, 0xCC0020);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (destinationHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                        destinationGraphics.ReleaseHdc(destinationHandle);
                    if (sourceHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                        sourceGraphics.ReleaseHdc(sourceHandle);
                }
                bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work okay, but, it always draws exactly what I see on my monitor. More specifically, it will not just draw the control, but any windows overlapping my control's bounds will also be rendered in my bitmap. So, here is my ask:

1) Is it possible to get a rendering of just the control by itself? In other words, is it possible to filter out any overlapping windows or controls on top of my control?

2) Is it possible to get a rendering of the entire control, even parts that are not currently visible in my application (say, for example, if my control is 800 pixels in height but I have minimized my window to 400 pixels such that I only see 400 of the 800 pixels - can I get the entire 800 pixels to render to a bitmap)?

Comment: `BitBlt` is not "rendering", it's "copying". You'd need `Control.DrawToBitmap` but that's impossible if the `Control` resides in an external process.

Comment: @dymanoid The other application is not .NET based. Is there any similar alternative for `Control.DrawToBitmap` in the WinAPI?

Comment: I think the best you can have is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2836714/2846483)

Comment: @dymanoid Thanks for your help. Unfortunately that method seems to only accept window handles and not control handles. Otherwise you get back error code 1400, ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE.