# How To Printing Other Form In C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

i having a problem in C# printing method

Let Say, I have C# Form1 and Form2
Form1 had a button on it, it says Print Page Form2
Form2 didnt had anything on design or had anything on design

My objective was,
to print page Form2

I searching on the web Microsoft and Others, i finding the answer like this

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern long BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
    Bitmap memoryImage;

    private void CaptureScreen()
    {
        Graphics mygraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        Size s = this.Size;
        memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, mygraphics);
        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
        IntPtr dc1 = mygraphics.GetHdc();
        IntPtr dc2 = memoryGraphics.GetHdc();
        BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, dc1, 0, 0, 13369376);
        mygraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
        memoryGraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
    }


    private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CaptureScreenForm();
        printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;

        DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(NewForm.memoryImageSender, 0, 0);
    }`
```

Thats whole code for printing the Form1.
But its not My Objective, so forget it

This is what i have in Form2

```
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern long BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
    Bitmap memoryImage;

    public void CaptureScreenForm2()
    {
        Graphics mygraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        Size s = this.Size;
        memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, mygraphics);
        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
        IntPtr dc1 = mygraphics.GetHdc();
        IntPtr dc2 = memoryGraphics.GetHdc();
        BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, dc1, 0, 0, 13369376);
        mygraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
        memoryGraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
    }

    public Bitmap memoryImageSender
    {
        get
        {
            return memoryImage;
        }
    }
```

And so i call the Form2 in Form1 like this

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NewForm = new Form2();
    }

    private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewForm.CaptureScreenForm2();                       //Calling The Form2 CaptureScreen Method
        printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;

        DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    { 
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(NewForm.memoryImageSender, 0, 0); //Calling The Form2 MemoryImage Bitmap
    }
```

And my idea for this is failure, nothing printed :(
Does Anyone have idea to overcoming this problem? I already dont have any idea.

Oh yeah i already asked this in other forum
http://cboard.cprogramming.com/csharp-programming/160427-problem-printing-other-form-csharp-form.html

but no answer until now,

Comment: If you never show your Form2, I don't think it has any graphics to capture.

Comment: @nvoigt hey it works, but i dont think i liked the way it be, i'd love to have the form to be printed is hidden, is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: @Geofff your code grabs the screen buffer. There will be nothing to grab if you dont show anything. You need a new method to extract the image data - one that operates on contols. This is not easy in winforms. Consider WPF? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881317/c-sharp-windows-form-control-to-image

Comment: @Gusdor I see and i understand. Is WPF better than WinForms to be printed?

Comment: @Geofff see for yourself http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969775.aspx. The saddest fact is that a proper reporting technology would be the best solution. WPF make writing these easier as well with `FlowDocument`.